# Cookies não funcionam

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

Ola gente um amigo aqui do fórum me ajudou a fazer um botão e eu agradeço muito a ele, funcionou perfeitamente. Porem falhei em colocar cookies e não estou entendendo onde estou errando (estava acompanhando um video no youtube para faze-lo)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Contador</title>
</head>
<body>

<script language="JavaScript">


function dispara( span ) {
conta( span, document.getElementsByClassName(span)[0]);
}

function conta( botao, contador ) {

document.getElementById(botao).disabled=true;

if(validaCookie()){

contador.innerHTML = contador.innerHTML -1;
criarCookie(contador.innerHTML);

}
else{
contador.innerHTML = 60;
criarCookie(60);
}

if(contador.innerHTML <= 0) {
document.getElementById(botao).disabled=false;
invalidarCookie();
return false;
}

setTimeout( function(){conta( botao, contador )}, 1000 );
}

</script>

<input type="button" value="botao1" onclick="dispara('s1')" id="s1" class="btn">
<span class="s1" id="sp1">60</span>

<script type="text/javascript">
if(validaCookie()){
document.getElementById("sp1").innerHTML = lendoCookie();
}

//Criando o Cookie
function criarCookie(valorCookie){

//Criar objeto Date
var data = new Date()
//Setando o tempo de vida do Cookie
data.setTime(data.getTime() + 600000);

//Criando a estrutura do Cookie
document.cookie = "cookieCount="+valorCookie+"; expires="+
data.toUTCString()+"; path=/";

}

//Validando a existência do Cookie
function validaCookie(){
if(document.cookie.indexOf("cookieCount") == (-1)){
return false;
}else{
return true;
}
}

//Lendo o conteúdo do Cookie
function lendoCookie(){

//document.cookie retorna chave=valor
var valor = document.cookie.split("=");
return valor[1];

}

//Invalidando o Cookie
function invalidarCookie() {
document.cookie = "cookieCount=0; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC; path=/";
alert("Cookie invalidado!");
}


</script>

</body>
</html>﻿
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boa tarde,

como você não informou qual erro estava dando, coloquei seu código em um fiddle e apareceram alguns erros que diziam respeito à ordem de carregamento do script.

Como regra geral, o ideal é colocar o script no final do body e não usar javascript inline para fazer bind de eventos, principalmente em razão da separação de conceitos (ainda, se o javascript está no final, ele não encontra a função que não foi carregada ainda).

Então coloquei um `addEventListener` para o botão, e fiz alguns testes e o comportamento (que eu acho que é) parece o esperado (pelo menos está lendo e escrevendo os cookies corretamente).

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mrlew/ce153vaL/

Comment: Vlw, era mais ou  menos isso que eu queria mesmo! Agora eu só vou colocar onload aqui!